# How do I replace values in CSS file in C#?

Tags: c#, css, .net

I have a CSS file with data as follows:

```
@font-face{font-family:"AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold";font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;src:url(/AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AkzidenzGroteskBE-Regular";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(/AkzidenzGroteskBE-Regular.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AmericanTypewriterStd-Med";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(/AmericanTypewriterStd-Med.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AvantGarde Bold";font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;src:url(/AvantGarde-Bold.ttf);}
@font-face{font-family:"FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(/FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd.otf);}
```

I want to make it:

```
@font-face{font-family:"AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold";font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;src:url(../Fonts/AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AkzidenzGroteskBE-Regular";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(../Fonts/AkzidenzGroteskBE-Regular.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AmericanTypewriterStd-Med";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(../Fonts/AmericanTypewriterStd-Med.otf);}
@font-face{font-family:"AvantGarde Bold";font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;src:url(../Fonts/AvantGarde-Bold.ttf);}
@font-face{font-family:"FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd";font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;src:url(../Fonts/FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd.otf);}
```

I have added `../Fonts/` in the reference at the end of each line.

I am trying to read each line and use multiple `substring` to find out the value between `(` and `);}`.

It is becoming very complicated. Please provide a simple solution.

Comment: it depends on the structure of your project. The path of your fonts will change in function of your folders. You need to show us where your fonts are and you css file too.

Comment: What you have above is a simple string replace.  Sounds like you're complicating things.  Does `File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace(":url(/Fonts", ":url(../Fonts")` give you what you're looking for?

Comment: @Corey i think you misunderstood something...

Comment: Actually, the main software that is creating the file is missing out on the `../Fonts/` part, which is why I am asked to insert the path manually via programming. Because without the proper path, the reference is invalid.

Comment: @Corey - The main file does not have `/Fonts` which makes each line unique. That is where the problem lies. Had it been `XML`, it would have been easy.

Comment: @PrimoChalice you use StackOverflow quite extensively to find answers to your questions please make sure to also mark the answers that helped you so other users can find it and get the same help you received. I answered 2 of your questions in the last days and you never reacted or gave any kind of feedback if your issue was solved or not

Comment: @DenisSchaf - I am so sorry, I will mark the answers from now on.

Comment: no problem the idea is just if we step back for a moment to help others we want that moment of satisfaction when we know that we were actually able to help you out with your problem. if we never get feedback this whole procedure gets quite frustrating after a while

Comment: I totally understand and accept my mistake. Will surely do so from now on :)

Comment: hey use this regex simply       :url(.*);   You will get url data in group one to replace it with your generic format

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
YourDiv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("src", "url(../Fonts/AkzidenzGroteskBE-Bold.otf)");
```

Comment: This will only replace one value, right? I have multiple unique values

Comment: Yes this will replace only this value. For everyone of the values, you have to add another line with the new url..